# What does it mean "bites the dust"

Tags: idioms

As heard in "Another One Bites the Dust", by Queen and "Elastic Heart"  by Sia.

Comment: It is an idiomatic expression you can easily find in dictionaries. ***To bite the dust*** : 
 Sl. to die. *A shot rang out, and another cowboy bit the dust. The soldier was too young to bite the dust.* http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+the+dust

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - this is not a duplicate, but a GR one.

Comment: @Josh61 What is GR?

Comment: General Reference.

Comment: It's both then!  In any case I've voted to close.

Comment: @josh61: Even if it's not the case in Queens song, "Bite the dust" also means "fail; suffer defeat". *This idiom sometimes mean that somebody had crashed, for example when riding a bike. If they "bite the dust", it implies that they no longer are on their bike, but instead have their face in the dirt.  "Another one bites the dust" is a variant that just means that out of a group of many, one more person has dropped out (for example has been eliminated competitively, has failed, or has died)*.

Comment: "Bite the dust" can be easily understood to be derived from a metaphor of a soldier (or other person) being shot dead and falling face-forward to the ground.